# In orientdb what is difference between in('edge_type') and in(edge_type)

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb2.2

Trying this query in Grateful dead database provided in orientdb gives 146 records:
`select expand(in('sung_by')) from V where name = 'Garcia'`

But when we try the similar version of below query: `select expand(in(sung_by)) from V where name = 'Garcia'`,  150 records are returned

Is it a bug?? Just trying orientdb from past week, followed tutorial from this [website](http://pettergraff.blogspot.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-orientdb.html) and this was second issue found.

Comment: You've got a neo4j tag here, but nothing in this question has to do with neo4j. You may want to remove the tag.

Comment: i was just hoping people who used neo4j would have looked into orientdb so i tagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `select expand(in(sung_by))`, the value of the field `sung_by` is resolved at query execution, but there is no field called `sung_by`, so it's null.

For this reason, it's like executing `select expand(in())` in that case. By using `'sung_by'`, instead, only the edges with label `sung_by` will be traversed.

So, put always `"` or `'` around edge's class/label to traverse.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. can you give a valid example of that case. i was trying after your answer to do a sub query within in(), will it be possible?